# API REST filtro entre dos rangos de fecha

Tags: php, mysql, date

Actualmente tengo la función GET obteniendo un identificador (id, nombre, etc). pero me encuentro en la necesidad de crear un API que pueda filtrar los registros entre dos fechas en especifico.

```
    public function measure_get(){
    $id = $this->get('id');
    if(count($this->get())>1){
        $response = array(
            "status"=>"error",
            "status_code"=>409,
            "message"=>"Too many params was sent",
            "validations"=>array(
                "id"=>"Send Id (Get) to get specific measure, or empty to get all measure"
            ),
            "data"=>null
        );
    }else{
        if($id){
            $response = $this->DAO->entitySelection('measure',array('idMeasure'=>$id),TRUE);
        }else{
            $response = $this->DAO->entitySelection('measure');
        }
    }
    $this->response($response,200);
}
```

esta es la función del controlador que manda a llamar al método entitySelection del modelo.

```
    function entitySelection($entityName, $whereClause = NULL, $isUnique = FALSE){
    if($whereClause){
        $this->db->where($whereClause);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get($entityName);
    if($this->db->error()['message']!=""){
        $reponseDB = array(
            "status"=>"error",
            "status_code"=>409,
            "message"=>"Db error: ".$this->db->error()['message'],
            "validations"=>null,
            "data"=>null
        );
    }else{
        $reponseDB = array(
            "status"=>"success",
            "status_code"=>200,
            "message"=>"Data loaded, successful",
            "validations"=>null,
            "data"=>$isUnique ? $query->row() : $query->result()
        );
    }
    return $reponseDB;
}
```

función que llama el controlador para saber el nombre de la tabla y el identificador con el cual realizar la búsqueda

[image: tabla de la cual filtrar por fecha]

alguna idea de como poder modificar mis métodos para que realice una búsqueda entre dos rangos de fecha

Comment: Los códigos van como texto por favor

Comment: Sin conocer el método `where()` de tu clase va a ser muy difícil poder ayudarte.